# put data into Azure Blob Storage from external sources

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, sharing

I have an Azure Blob Storage that I would like to use as a repository for sharing data with external parties.
So basically, each two days someone should send .csv file into such a repository without accessing into the azure portal but only viewing the Azure Blob Storage as a repository where put new data.
is there a way to share, for instance, a link, with secure access, and put the new data every two days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to share, for instance, a link, with secure access, and
> put the new data every two days?

Absolutely. You can create a `Shared Access Signature (SAS) URL` with at least `Write` or `Create` permission and using that URL your users will be able to upload the files in your storage account blob container.

You can learn more about SAS here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature.

In your particular scenario, I would recommend that you create a SAS URL either on the blob container where you want your users to upload the file or at the blob level (if you know the name of the file you want). For this you will need to create a [`Service Shared Access Signature`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas) instead of an [`Account Shared Access Signature`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas).

Another thing you might want to look into is `Azure Data Share` service. Please see this link on how you can securely receive data using this service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-share/subscribe-to-data-share?tabs=azure-portal.